# Android test startAcitivityForResult and onActivityResult

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-instrumentation

I have two activities; `ActivityA` and `ActivityB`. I want to test the following interaction ([Video here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1H823WsrNebWxIw-e2xXNvkOks8lN1SxE/view?usp=sharing)):

- Start at `ActivityA`
- Tap on the "Go To ActivityB" button
- Test if `ActivityB` is started for result and test its intent and also the value of `ActivityB#starVisibility`
- Toggle the switch in `ActivityB`
- Press back
- Check if the star in `ActivityA`'s visibility has been updated (Ideally check the result code and intent)

These are my files:

activity_a.xml:

```xml
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/star"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@android:drawable/btn_star" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/goToB_btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Go To ActivityB" />
</LinearLayout>
```

activity_b.xml:

```xml
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Switch
        android:id="@+id/visibilitySwitch"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Show Activity A star" />
</LinearLayout>
```

ActivityA.kt:

```kotlin
class ActivityA : AppCompatActivity() {
    lateinit var starImageView: ImageView

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_a)

        title = "Activity A"

        starImageView = findViewById(R.id.star)
        findViewById<Button>(R.id.goToB_btn).setOnClickListener { goToActivityB() }
    }

    @Suppress("DEPRECATION")
    fun goToActivityB() {
        val data = Intent(this, ActivityB::class.java).apply {
            putExtra("starVisibility", starImageView.isVisible)
        }
        startActivityForResult(data, 1)
    }

    @Deprecated("Deprecated in Java")
    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

        starImageView.isVisible = data!!.getBooleanExtra("starVisibility", false)
    }
}
```

ActivityB.kt:

```kotlin
class ActivityB : AppCompatActivity() {
    var starVisibility: Boolean? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_b)

        title = "Activity B"

        starVisibility = intent.getBooleanExtra("starVisibility", false)
        findViewById<Switch>(R.id.visibilitySwitch).run {
            isChecked = starVisibility!!
            setOnCheckedChangeListener { _, checked -> starVisibility = checked }
        }
    }

    override fun onBackPressed() {
        setResult(
            RESULT_OK,
            Intent().apply { putExtra("starVisibility", starVisibility) }
        )
        finish()
    }
}
```

I've tried writing an Instrumented test but it wouldn't pass in CI and was extremely flaky. Is there a way to unit-test navigation and `startActivityForResult` and `onBackPressed`?

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't using the Activity Result APIs instead of `startActivityForResult`, which [explicitly supports testing without actually starting the other activity or handling back presses](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result#test)? This is exactly the kind of thing that wasn't possible with the `startActivityForResult` API and why it is deprecated.

Comment: @ianhanniballake Do you know of any examples of tests for actvity to activity interactions? The test in the android docs and everywhere I looked where only for activity to fragment interactions